# Grabbing data from websites

Tags: ios

I am just wondering how you would go about grabbing articles from BBC and automatically updating this information in an iOS app. So basically what I want to do is add new articles to my application automatically whenever BBC release them. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple.. Grab the sample code from this tutorial. http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-rss-reader-tutorial/

and in APPMasterViewController.m change url to something like

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml”];
```

you can get other types of news feeds from their page http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/10628494..

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this by getting the information from their RSS Feed.

http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/world/us_and_canada/rss.xml

it will return you an XML document and you can parse it and dispaly them in your app

sample article info

```
  <title>US boy charged in death of teacher</title>
      <description>A 14-year-old boy has been charged in the death of a teacher whose body was found in woodland behind her school.</description>
      <link>http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-24644203#sa-ns_mchannel=rss&amp;ns_source=PublicRSS20-sa</link>
      <guid isPermaLink="false">http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-24644203</guid>
      <pubDate>Wed, 23 Oct 2013 19:03:05 GMT</pubDate>
      <media:thumbnail width="66" height="49" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/70673000/jpg/_70673073_chism.jpg"/>
      <media:thumbnail width="144" height="81" url="http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/70673000/jpg/_70673074_chism.jpg"/>
    </item>
```

Comment: Thank you I will try that tomorrow

Comment: @avi you need to get the rss.xml every time user opens or refresh your view for new data.

Answer (score 0):

Check out APIs for developers from this link:

```
http://www.bbc.co.uk/developer/technology/apis.html
```

Grab your api and parse date - in my opinion JSON is the most comfortable format on iOS.

Then you could compare fresh, parsed data to data on the device and check is there something new.